# want to increment field value in mongodb using sails in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I want to increment the field value by 1 in update query using sails(node)

```
Users.update({ code: referral }, { $inc: [{ referredCount: 1 }] }).then(function (update) {})
 I have tried this.

Users.update({ code: referral }, { $inc: [{ referredCount: 1 }] }).then(function (update) {})


 "err": {
            "error": "E_UNKNOWN",
            "status": 500,
            "summary": "Encountered an unexpected error",
            "raw": {
                "name": "MongoError",
                "message": "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$inc' in '$inc' is not valid for storage.",
                "driver": true,
                "index": 0,
                "code": 52,
                "errmsg": "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$inc' in '$inc' is not valid for storage."
            }
        }
```

Comment: try { $inc: { referredCount: 1 }}

Comment: @sushantmehta Not working

Comment: @AbhishekBansal whats your schema or the data looks like? on top of which you are performing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only correct way to do it.

```
Users.update({ code: referral }, { $inc: { referredCount: 1 } })
```

If its not incrementing, check whether referredCount exists in the document or not.
If it exists then check whether its not nested in another object.
Lastly also check whether, there is an actual document of the applied filter by query below.

```
Users.find({ code: referral })
```

Comment: referredCount: {
            type: 'integer',
            defaultsTo: 0,
        },

Comment: this is the field in Users model

Comment: Are you able to find a record using Users.find({ code: referral })?

Comment: Please check the updated code. I think you should write referral as 'referral', if it is not dynamic

Comment: I am able to find record record using Users.find and referral is dynamic

Comment: Okay. Is there a field named referredCount in the found document?

Comment: If the field is there, check whether its value is in number or string in the document.

Comment: Also can you please attach the found document. I want to see its structure.

Comment: firstName: 'abhishek',
    lastName: 'bansal',
    username: 'bikere@yopmail.com',
    referral: '738536360',
    code: 347958811,
    Type: 'U',
    roles: 'U',
    referralLink: 'http://localhost:3000/signup?code=347958811',
    fullName: 'abhishek bansal',
    date_registered: '2019-09-19T12:30:45.776Z',
    date_verified: '2019-09-19T12:48:42.949Z',
    status: 'active',
    lat: '0',
    lng: '0',
    isVerified: 'Y',
    isDeleted: false,
    referredCount: 0,
    referralAmount: 0,
    createdAt: '2019-09-19T12:30:46.041Z',
    updatedAt: '2019-09-19T12:48:42.950Z',

Comment: value of field is a integer

Comment: All looks good. Can you send me the dynamic value of referral. Exact value. String or number